# Updating Array with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to update a useState array with form values.  This code does not work properly.  Scratching my head as to why.  The function to look at is handleGaugeSubmit.
When the loop is finished, the array is only populated with the last element.  Many thanks.

```
const InputFields = () => {
  const [numStrings, setNumStrings] = useState(0);
  const [gauges, setGauges] = useState([]);
  const [nutWidth, setNutWidth] = useState(0.0);

  const runCallback = (cb) => {
    return cb();
  };

  const handleGaugeSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    for (var i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
      setGauges([...gauges, event.target[i].value]);
    }
    return;
  };

  const handleStringNumberSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNumStrings(event.target[0].value);
    return;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleStringNumberSubmit}>
        <label>Number of strings</label>

        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Set number of strings" />
      </form>

      <form onSubmit={handleGaugeSubmit}>
        {runCallback(() => {
          const html = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
            html.push(
              <>
                <label>String {i + 1}</label>

                <input type="text" />
              </>,
            );
          }
          return html;
        })}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      {gauges.toString()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputFields;
```

Comment: `setGauges` is asynchronous in terms of updating state, meaning that when you call it for the first time, the `gauges` is sill empty, so that in loop you actually just concatenate an empty array with a `event.target[i].value` which always gives an array with one element.

Comment: You would want to create a temp array of all the elements you want to insert into state ... Then do it in one shot like --> setGauges([...gauges, ...tempArr])

Comment: @SiddharthSeth, this works.  Feel dumb for not thinking of this.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Answer was thanks to @SiddarthSeth.  Instead of setting state each pass of the loop, the correct approach is build an array of all elements I want to add, then call setGauges once.

Working solution:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    const newElements = []
    for (var i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        newElements.push(event.target[i].value);
    }
    setGauges([...gauges, ...newElements]);
    return;
  };
```